# Dynamically and conditionally summarize columns

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

What I am trying to do is a bit hard, I don`t know if it is possible using only Excel, but here it goes.

I have a list of products, with its corresponding components, each component is also a product, so it can have more components.

Each product has the column "Custo", wich is the cost of this product.
The cost of the product is the sum of the cost of its components.

The first column of the sheet is the "level" of the component inside that product, so for example, the product on the first line has the level "1.1", his cost is 4,0734. If you look at its components, 1.1.1, 1.1.2, 1.1.3, 1.1.4, 1.1.5, the sum of their costs is exactly 4,0734.

I need to create a formula in each product, that does this calculation, so the cost of the 1.1, is the sum of the costs of the 1.1.n (without considering the 1.1.1.n, or 1.1.2.n, just the first level).

[Excel Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8YiSh.png)

Comment: Not a fully formed answer, but I suspect the easiest approach will be to use helper columns to split the costs into different columns according to the level - use LEN to determine the length of the "level" name eg 1+((LEN($A2)-1)/2).
Alternative might be a single helper column for the "parent" level by stripping off last two characters, then use SUMIFs for where the "parent level" equals the current level. Eg 1.1.3 has parent level of 1.1, which you could put in column O, then the cost of 1.1.3  is included in the parent cost using SUMIF($O$2:$O$9999,$A2,$I$2:$I$9999)

Comment: adding to @AdamV comment, `sumifs` formula can accept wildcards in the criteria. For example you can use the criteria `"1.1.?"` which will look for matches with with the same first 2 digits and the a single character in the `?` location. Any item with additional characters would not be considered a match.

Comment: First, you're on the right track - Excel will do this.  Even Excel 2010 can pull this off, but with a harder path. I once did something similar to count total employees reporting to each person (sans VBA). Second, there is something missing to me - where are the component unit costs in your example? Is your Custo an illustration of the the expected outcome? If so, where does it pick up its unit costs?

Comment: @Darkuin ,,, If U look at column A,,,  A2"A27,,  `1.1` is a unique code,,,, possibly has more below,,, and if you wanna to get the SUM of 1.1 only then you may use SUMIF/SUMPRODUCT ,, it will never consider others like 1.1.1, 1.2 !!

Answer (score 0):

If you have a column containing your unit costs, then you could sum them up according to the level as you proposed.  If your table had also a "costo unitario", then the formula would be:

```
=SUMIFS([costo unitario],[nivel],[@nivel]&"*")
```

Using your table, let's assume that **unit costs** are in **column O**, then the formula for Custo would be:

```
=SUMIFS(O2:O100,A2:A100,A2:A100&"*")
```

You could put that formula into I2 (custo) and it will create a dynamic array in Column I in Excel 2019/365.  If you have Excel 2016 or 13 or lower, then put

```
=SUMIFS(O2:O100,A2:A100,A2&"*")
```

in I2 and enter it with CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER and then copy that down the column.